# how to close browser using officjs

Tags: office-js

I'm developing MS office add-ins using Office-JS and angular for MS word, im keeping file on https://office.live.com and insert manifest.xml as add-ins. can i know how to close the main browser tab (where online word document displaying) when i called any event or function using officsjs inside add-ins plugin. I have try with window.close but its working for only plugin window not for main tab. Any solution for this matter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but there is no API in Office JS that will close the outer browser window that is hosting Word Online. Consider making this a request at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).